# Why is my Directive throwing "Error: $injector:unpr Unknown Provider"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've working on refactoring my Controllers, Factories and Directives to the recommended [Angular-Style-Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide#file-templates-and-snippets) for [Angular Snippets](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/tree/master/assets/sublime-angular-snippets).

I've gotten the Controllers and Factories working correctly with the new style, but not the Directives.

`Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- platformHeaderDirective`

**The new Directive style with errors:**

```
(function() { "use strict";

    angular
        .module('platformHeaderDirectives', [])
        .directive('platformHeader', directive);
    directive.$inject = ['$scope'];
    /* @ngInject */
    function directive ($scope) {
        var directive = {
            templateUrl : "header/platform_header/platformHeader.html",
            restrict    : "E",
            replace     : true,
            bindToController: true,
            controller: Controller,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            link: link,
            scope: {
            }
        };
        return directive;
        function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }
    /* @ngInject */
    function Controller () {

    }
})();
```

**My old working Directive that does not throw errors:**

```
(function() { "use strict";

    angular.module('platformHeaderDirectives', [])

    .directive('platformHeader', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl : "header/platform_header/platformHeader.html",
            restrict    : "E",
            replace     : true,
            scope       : false,
            controller  : ['$scope',
                           function($scope) {

                /** Init platformHeader scope */
                // var vs = $scope;

            }]
        }
    });

})();
```

Comment: Directive does not take a `scope` injection. Please remove it and try.

Comment: @Chandermani ah! That was it!!! Thanks :) Hmm I need to do a issue request for that repo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$scope` can not be injected to directive. i have changed code to inject `$scope` in controller of directive.

**Code:**

```js
(function() { "use strict";

    angular
        .module('platformHeaderDirectives', [])
        .directive('platformHeader', directive);
    
    /* @ngInject */
    function directive () {
        var directive = {
            templateUrl : "header/platform_header/platformHeader.html",
            restrict    : "E",
            replace     : true,
            bindToController: true,
            controller: Controller,
            controllerAs: 'vm',
            link: link,
            scope: {
            }
        };
        return directive;
        function link(scope, element, attrs) {

        }
    }
    /* @ngInject */
    Controller.$inject = ['$scope'];
    function Controller ($scope) {

    }
})();
```

Answer (score 5):

I know you got your answer but let me explain the actual picture.

$scope is not a service(`$scopeProvider` is not exist in angular js) it is something special that is injected by angular itself into the controller as a child of `$rootScope.`

so you cannot explicitly inject it in service,directive...etc.

But as the answer explained by 'jad-panda' you can inject it explicitly in the controller of direcitve (not directly to the directive).

Comment: Thanks for the additional feedback :)