# Accessing $scope From a Directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, svg, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Due to our lack of expertise in developing with AngularJS, we've come to another roadblock in our development process.

We are developing a Angular/Web API application where our page only consists of an interactive SVG diagram that displays data when a user hovers over a particular SVG  tag in an Angular directive.

There are currently two custom directives in the application.

1. Directive One - Loads SVG file into web page
2. Directive Two - Adds SVG  element hover event/data filter

[image]

**DIRECTIVE ONE:**

```
//directive loads SVG into DOM
angular.module('FFPA').directive('svgFloorplan', ['$compile', function  ($compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',

    templateUrl: 'test.svg',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        var groups = element[0].querySelectorAll("g[id^='f3']")
        angular.forEach(groups, function (g,key) {
            var cubeElement = angular.element(g);
            //Wrap the cube DOM element as an Angular jqLite element.
            cubeElement.attr("cubehvr", "");
            $compile(cubeElement)(scope);
        })
    }
}
}]);
```

The SVG diagram contains  tags with unique identifiers, ie:

```
<g id="f3s362c12"></g>
```

Directive Two loads JSON data from an injected service that corresponds to each of the SVG  tag id's.

```
 //filters json based on hover item
 dataService.getData().then(function(data) {
    thisData = data.filter(function (d) {
    return d.seatId.trim() === groupId
 });
```

As shown above, Directive Two also adds a hover event function that filters the JSON data based on the  tag that was hovered over.

IE: If a user hovers over , a filter in the directive would return this JSON record:

```
{"Id":1,
 "empNum":null,
 "fName":" Bun E.",
 "lName":"Carlos",
  ...
 "seatId":"f3s362c12 ",
 "floor":3,
 "section":"313 ",
 "seat":"12 "}
```

**DIRECTIVE TWO:**

```
//SVG hover directive/filter match json to svg
angular.module("FFPA").directive('cubehvr', ['$compile', 'dataService',     function ($compile, dataService) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {

        //id of group 
        scope.elementId = element.attr("id");
        //alert(scope.elementId);
        var  thisData;
        //function call
        scope.cubeHover = function () {

            //groupId is the id of the element hovered over.
            var groupId = scope.elementId;

            //filters json based on hover item
            dataService.getData().then(function(data) {
            thisData = data.filter(function (d) {
                return d.seatId.trim() === groupId
            });
              //return data.seatId === groupId
              scope.gData = thisData[0];
              alert(thisData[0].fName + " " + thisData[0].lName + " " +   thisData[0].deptId);  
            });
            //after we get a match, we need to display a tooltip with   save/cancel buttons.
            $scope.empData = $scope.gData;
        };
        element.attr("ng-mouseover", "cubeHover()");
        element.removeAttr("cubehvr");
        $compile(element)(scope);
    }
    //,
    //controller: function($scope, $element){
    // $scope.empData = $scope.gData;
    //}
  }
}]);
```

The problem we now have is now (besides having minimal Angular experience and facing a unique and difficult implementation problem) is that we're trying to implement a way to create a tooltop using a div tag and an angular scope variable that we can display when a user hovers over the SVG tag element (instead of a Javascript alert which is demonstrated in the Plunker POC link below).

Since the data is being driven by the directive and the directive is already taking "cubehvr" as a parameter:

```
angular.module("FFPA").directive('*cubehvr*', ['$compile', 'dataService', function ($compile, dataService)
```

We're stuck since we don't know how to set an HTML page scope directive or variable, say like this from our second directive:

```
<div uib-popover="Last Name: {{empData.lName}}" 
    popover-trigger="'mouseenter'" 
    type="div" 
    class="btn btn-default">Tooltip
</div>
```

Or as simple as say, this:

```
  <div emp-info></div>
```

The div tooltips will have html buttons that call Web API Update functionality.

We have a scaled down POC Plunk here:

[POC Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/fFitR3BQZ8T1NBbFoNJ0?p=preview)

Also were thinking about using the Angular Bootstrap UI for the toolips:

[Bootstrap UI Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/wtT8sUpgyVX7MVOcCtr9?p=preview)

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Im not sure I understand what it is you want to do. Basically, you want to find a way to share a `scope` variable value across directives, is that correct?

Comment: From my limited understanding of Angular, I think that is correct.  In the second Directive, we're thinking if we can access or set a value in a div tag based on the item the user hovers over, we can create a div toolip to display to the user.  We currently don't know how to do this.  I hope that answers your question.  Thanks

Comment: Yea, I think that makes sense. So, the first problem you are having with your code, is you are trying to use `$scope` but have not injected it anywhere -- though you do have `scope`. Unless you want to get super fancy with using isolate scopes, if you want to pass values between directives, you could either look at binding them to `$rootScope` or passing them around using a factory or service. And honestly, if you guys have limited experience with Angular, keep it super simple. Don't try and do everything perfectly, but rather get it working and come back to it when you understand it.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Do you have an example of how we can do this in the context of our current problem?  Tried to inject scope into: angular.module("FFPA").directive('cubehvr', ['$scope', '$compile', 'dataService', function ($scope, $compile, dataService) {}.  Getting error:  Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope <- cubehvrDirective

Comment: Yea, idk if using `$scope` is what you want to do at all. Depending on what you want to do, you can declare the same `controller` for both directives and use that to access a shared scope. To be honest, im still not 100% clear on what you want. That being said, to pass data around, I would look at using isolated scopes or just using a service/factory to pass values between directives.

Comment: Just looked at this post where the error seems to be the same as I am getting when attempting to inject $scope into a directive.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30271903/why-is-my-directive-throwing-error-injectorunpr-unknown-provider

Apparently $scope cannot be injected into a directive. 

Tough stuff..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138870/discussion-between-jazzbox-and-pytth).

Comment: @jazzBox I read your question again and found out that your question is multi-layered and I didn't fully answer it. I edited my entry. Hopefully now it's fully working and understable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

//Edit. I read your question once again and go thru my answer. I didn't fully answer your question as it's multi-layered. Now I'll go thru all your concerns and try to answer them:

1. Passing $scope to the other directives.

$scope is Model-View in MVVM design pattern, it glues your Template (View) and your Model together. In theory you could probably pass the $scope to the other directive, but I think it's an anti-pattern.

2. Communication between directives.There are at least 4 methods which you can use to communicate your directives:

   - Share the same scope, what you almost did in your plunker, just don't define any 'scope' in your directives' spec. I'm not sure if it's the best way to go with as any of your directives can malform your scope's data.
   - Create isolated scopes and use ng-model or $watch, it's safer method, but it needs more overhead. In such case you pass the variable down, which you scope.$watch. It's two-way-binding. You can push and pull the value.
     [$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch)
   - Create a service, where you keep something like an event-bus or a storage for your variables
   - You can communicate your directives with events:
     [$on](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$on)
     [$emit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$emit)
     That works well with hierarchical directives (so effectively, you would have to create isolated child scopes)
3. Add popover to a SVG's child. Bootstrap has an ability to add popover to body instead of to parent element. It's useful for SVGs: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#popover

I refactored your code to use two directives, and the data is loaded in controller. One directive wraps the popover and the second one passes the data, also the popover uses template now, so it's being compiled with angular:

```
  var app = angular.module('FFPA',  ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);

  //controller
  app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope, dataService) {
    $scope.test = 'test';
    dataService.getData().then(function(data) {
      $scope.dataset = data.reduce(function (obj, item) {
        obj[item.seatId.trim()] = item;
        item.fullName = item.fName + ' ' + item.lName;
        return obj;
      }, {});
    });
  });

  angular.module('FFPA').service('dataService', function($http){
    this.getData = function(){
      return $http.get("data.json").then(
        function(response){
          return response.data;
        }, function() {
          return {err:"could not get data"};
        }
      );
    }
  });

  //directive loads SVG into DOM
  angular.module('FFPA').directive('svgFloorplan', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'test.svg',
        scope: {
          'dataset': '=svgFloorplan'
        },
        link: {
          pre: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var groups = element[0].querySelectorAll("g[id^='f3']");
            scope.changeName = function (groupId) {
              if (scope.dataset[groupId] && scope.dataset[groupId].lastName.indexOf('changed') === -1) {
                scope.dataset[groupId].lastName += ' changed';
              }
            }

            groups.forEach(function(group) {
              var groupId = group.getAttribute('id');
              if (groupId) {
                var datasetBinding = "dataset['" + groupId + "']";
                group.setAttribute('svg-floorplan-popover', datasetBinding);

                $compile(group)(scope);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      }
  }]);

  angular.module('FFPA').directive('svgFloorplanPopover', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
          'person': '=svgFloorplanPopover'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          scope.changeName = function () {
            if (scope.person && scope.person.fullName.indexOf('changed') === -1) {
              scope.person.fullName += ' changed';
            }
          }
          scope.htmlPopover = 'popoverTemplate.html';
          element[0].setAttribute('uib-popover-template', "htmlPopover");
          element[0].setAttribute('popover-append-to-body', 'true');
          element[0].setAttribute('popover-trigger', "'outsideClick'");
          element[0].querySelector('text').textContent += '{{ person.fullName }}';

          element[0].removeAttribute('svg-floorplan-popover');

          $compile(element)(scope);

        }
      }
  }]);
```

And your HTML body now looks like:

```
  <body style="background-color:#5A8BC8;">
    <div ng-app="FFPA" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <div svg-floorplan="dataset"></div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

HTML for popover:

```
  <div><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="changeName()">{{ person.fullName }}</button></div>
```

Here is working plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/uHgnZ1ZprZRDvL0uIkcH?p=preview

Comment: Thanks.
The hover only seems to be displaying the name for one person (Robin Zander), but there are four people, one in each cube.
1). Bun E. Carlos 2). Rick Neilson 3).  Robin Zander 4). Tom Petersson.

Comment: Yup, because in the plunker which I sent you, it uses only the first entry: thisData[0], you can loop over or pass the whole set to your scope. Just do: scope.name.set = thisData; (That's line 71 in script.js)

Comment: I think something else is wrong.  In our previous version we were able to identify the cube id that a user hovered over when scope:true: http://plnkr.co/edit/bzYjzxLZGBGDYoDZK2xl?p=preview

However in the new directive, where scope was removed, the directive always sees the cube hovered over as f3s362c1

Comment: I updated the code to return the right values. Consider moving the on hover handler to the upper level of your directives and track, which element you hover on. Something what jQuery delegate (or 'on' functionality with 3 params) does. You can pass $event parameter to your onHover function in your template: instead "cubeHover('" + elementId + "')" do "cubeHover($event)"

Comment: Thanks Oskar.  We chose Angular since it was recommended as a solution to working with SVG and having experience in Javascript/Jquery as an API into the HTML DOM, we thought it would be fairly easy to pick up, but quickly found out that to be an incorrect assumption.  There seems to be a pretty steep learning curve to Angular.



Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @jazzBox No problem, thanks for accepting my solution. AngularJS has a terrible learning curve, but once you pick it up, it will be fairly easy to build new stuff. If it's not too late consider migrating to Angular (v2).If you can't, like in my case, take a time to read: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md

Comment: Since we're going to need to add line breaks and html buttons for update functionality, I updated the Plunk to add html, but the tags aren't rendering correctly.

Tried: group.setAttribute('uib-popover-html', $sce.trustAsHtml(htmlPopover));

Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139301/discussion-between-jazzbox-and-oskar).

Comment: I think that since we cannot add html elements to the popovers since they're being added to SVG, we still don't have an answer to this question.  Unless someone has a way to deal with this, we may need to create a new question to address this outstanding issue.

Comment: I think that's a separate problem, but try using uib-popover-html instead of uib-popover

Comment: At line 62:   $compile(group)(scope);
Getting this error:

Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token 'Zander' is an unexpected token at column 7 of the expression [Robin Zander] starting at [Zander].

http://plnkr.co/edit/F8W5o5xy7dnNqqyJB7f1?p=preview

Comment: Check my updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/uHgnZ1ZprZRDvL0uIkcH?p=preview I also changed the trigger type from mouseover to click to access the contents of your popover

Comment: Actually the `outsideClick` works better, to specify your own open - close events you need to use either $uibTooltipProvider or popover-is-open, but that's an another question to answer.

Comment: Although I'd have to defer to you on this point, since we aren't able to display a clickable button for update purposes, I don't think this implementation will fulfill our requirement that the popover is able to update the cube occupant via a button click.